# combobox1 to 2 selectedindex

Tags: c#, combobox

I having trouble on combobox selectedindex. basically i wanted to disable the button1 when my textbox result is 1. but the problem is when the button1 get disable and i chose another option it wont enable back. so is there another way to do it? below is just showing some part of the coding.

```
    double[,] arr; 
    public Form1()
    {
            arr = new double[3, 3];
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                arr[0, 0] = 1;
                arr[0, 1] = 0.79;
                arr[0, 2] = 1.17;
                arr[1, 0] = 1.26;
                arr[1, 1] = 1;
                arr[1, 2] = 1.08;
                arr[2, 0] = 0.85;
                arr[2, 1] = 0.93;
                arr[2, 2] = 1;
            }
        void CreateArray()
        {
        if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == -1 || comboBox2.SelectedIndex == -1)
            return;
        else if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1 || comboBox2.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            button1.Enabled = false;
        }
        else if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0 || comboBox2.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            button1.Enabled = false;
        }
        else if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1 || comboBox2.SelectedIndex == 2)
        {
            button1.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            button1.Enabled = true;
        }
```

Comment: Just curious, what is the purpose of that double array here?

Comment: what happen in your first case..just set buton.IsEnable= true;..

Comment: if you wanted to set Isenable of Button..you can do it on Combobox SelectionChanged Event ..it would be more easy..

Comment: How many items are present in the second combobox?

Comment: @tanuj_loop if i set first case button enable = true, [0,0] is not going disable the button. it disable when comboboxindex[0,1] [0,2]

Comment: can you provide the number of choices that user has with either combobox

Answer (score 2):

If the second combobox has only 3 items then you will never be able to reach the final else clause where you reset the button to the enabled state.

This happens because you use the || logical OR operator and with only three items you will always take one of the else if condition before the final else

Comment: no wonder its only works when there is only 2 items. but how i cant solve this? i'm still learning in process.

Comment: I think i solve it. I made the change on else if || to && 
    else if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1 && comboBox2.SelectedIndex == 1)
{
button1.Enabled = false;
}

Comment: Well. Good, The OR and AND logical operators are often a pitfall for beginners. I suggest always to put on a sheet of paper the condition required to have the button enabled and then translate the condition on code, by the way, if there is an answer that help you to resolve your problem remember to accept it (when the site allows you to do so)